# R use list of values as color scale

Tags: r, colors, plot, scale

I'd like to represent the value of a variable as a color of a dot in a scatter in R.

```
x <- rnorm(100) + 5
y <- rnorm(100) + 5
plot(x, y)
```

Here, I'd like to use a variable as input for the coloring. But if I try

```
plot(x, y, col = x)
```

I get something weird, probably obviously. Now I can get what I want like this:

```
x_norm = (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
col_fun <- colorRamp(c("blue", "red"))
rgb_cols <- col_fun(x_norm)
cols <- rgb(rgb_cols, maxColorValue = 256)
plot(x, y, col = cols)
```

[image]

But that seems a little elaborate, and to get it working with NA or NaN values, for example by giving them black as color, is not so easy. For me. Is there an easy way to do this that I'm overlooking?

Comment: As to why you are getting "something weird": colors are sorted and numbered in an internal palette. When you do `plot(x, y, col = x)`, the `col` argument is rounded down to integers and the appropriate color from this palette is used, which is why you get strips of identical colors, each strip with a width of exactly 1. Look at `?palette`. I added the plot to your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`cut`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/cut.html) for devide x into intervals and `colorRampPalette` for create fixed size palette:

```
x <- rnorm(100) + 5
y <- rnorm(100) + 5
maxColorValue <- 100
palette <- colorRampPalette(c("blue","red"))(maxColorValue)
plot(x, y, col = palette[cut(x, maxColorValue)])
```

Comment: But then how do you add a colorbar?  Colored points are almost useless without a colorbar...

Answer (score 1):

You could work with the predefined grayscale colors `gray0`, ..., `gray99` like this:

```
x <- rnorm(100) + 5
y <- rnorm(100) + 5
x.renormed <- floor(100*((x-min(x))/(diff(range(x))+1e-2)))
colors.grayscale <- paste("gray",x.renormed,sep="")
plot(x, y, col=colors.grayscale, bg=colors.grayscale,pch=21)
```

Result:

[image: grayscale scatterplot]