# How to plot colours for data frame values in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame of 168 values - below is an example:

```
[1] 10.20825145 10.49029738  9.47768668 11.37237685  9.77536685 -9.96578428  9.84730064 -9.96578428 -9.96578428  9.67701164  8.89308834
 [12] -9.96578428 -9.96578428 -9.96578428  4.88074954 10.83777007  9.67240471 11.55113265 12.29597119 11.17761580  1.27119342  5.89488206
 [23] 11.04314439 11.51956302  8.88611025  0.41593543 10.09092012  1.11935342  2.29304065  6.44051757  7.27223875  4.17286046 12.29597119
 [34]  8.93756226 -9.96578428  2.82374114 -9.96578428 -9.96578428  6.78451866  6.75725141  3.30799055  1.33285052 11.10138287  9.56310341
 [45]  6.05138487 11.16478498  0.64163540  2.25818628  6.84610893  0.90170156  5.03961679  8.06503755  1.91447714  1.99289237 10.05683543
 [56]  4.18387615  1.44569558  9.44208535 10.76103696 10.07250772  5.65824078 11.44590482  4.98525549  9.27145969  4.62079778 -9.96578428
 [67] -0.15866721  7.84066444 10.64691705  8.10132712 10.42130331  7.63017724  9.81489036 10.44605958  7.61256542 10.59292091 10.68115428
 [78]  8.63528904  7.08127497  9.37016682  9.72611928  8.79221371 11.37733558 10.13409536  8.54228484  9.19473411  9.22357213 -9.96578428
 [89]  2.06859467  7.85102680 10.21632083  7.32085557  7.17868855  7.29012838  9.39064690 11.21826736  0.99311790 10.73680716 -1.27079596
[100]  1.56468983 -1.53765829  1.52571260  7.59811777 11.25804316  5.76919580  1.46352533 10.66897438 -0.19396590 -9.96578428 -0.10920277
[111] 10.27374790  1.86021231  0.05229581  9.10927587  6.75497052 -9.96578428  7.37624442 -1.18384163 10.09532648 10.66210443  0.97845531
[122] -0.58780829  1.70242105  7.11891287 -1.00259672 -9.96578428  3.44482985  3.66543196  2.30526333  9.25052252  0.47603010  0.67767918
[133]  0.53495561 -9.96578428 -0.25681726 -0.88592846 12.28143934 11.48635730  1.57340309  1.81157359  5.22452852  2.82243460  2.63202605
[144] 10.96672824 11.39766334  6.32855877  3.35147803  1.85503403 11.07168816  0.62804624  1.26195498  1.84045927  2.36940606 10.72429922
[155]  9.03370799  0.17404750  0.35583693  0.01601167  8.74355131 10.53061214 -1.02983443 -9.96578428 11.00097153  2.29188360  4.60733174
[166]  0.72027563  1.33766127 -1.02773393
```

I know want to plot a graph whereby the colours for each datapoint move from red to green with an increase in value. I want to preserve the order of the data frame.

```
numbers <-(dataframe)
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow", "green"))(168))
plot(col= my_palette,numbers, pch=20)
```

However, this plots colours in ascending order of the data frame indices not the values.

Any advice on how to solve this would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353213/gradient-of-n-colors-ranging-from-color-1-and-color-2. When you use `plot(col= my_palette,numbers, pch=20) `, you are just giving a sequence of colors for your points, and therefore, it'll not care about the `numbers` variable at all.

Comment: You can also use the accepted answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885107/r-use-list-of-values-as-color-scale and treat his `x` as your `numbers` variable, remove everything related to his `y` variable and change the color scale to the one you want (red to green).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `col = my_pallete`, use `col = my_pallete[rank(numbers)]`